# Meross 3-way Switch Wiring

Tags: wiring

I am installing a Meross 3-way switch to replace one switch of a light that is controlled by two switches. The installed switch has 2 black wires and one red wire connected to it. One side of the switch has a black wire connected with a black screw, and a red wire connected with a gold screw, on the other side is the other black wire (gold screw).  The Meross 3-way switch has the following connections - L(black), T1(Red), T2(Black), N(White), GND(Green).

From what I can gather I should connect the black wire that is connected with the black screw to L, the red to T1, the other black to T2, white to the white wires bundled in the box, and the green to the box itself - but doesn't hurt to ask first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in your plan. The black wire connected to the black screw of the old switch is the line, the other black wire and the red wire connected to the two brass screws are the travelers and would go to the T1 and T2 of the new switch. The white wire from the switch to the group of white wires, neutrals. The green wire goes to a grounding screw on the metal box or to a group of bare copper ground wires